# How to deliver notifications with Sockets on AWS?

Tags: node.js, notifications, amazon-web-services, socket.io, pyramid

I'm in a project where I need to create a notification system. It's for a website created with the Pyramid framework that runs on the AWS infrastructure (I think the server is apache or paste, not sure).

When a user follows something, all friends should instantly get a notification that states "X is now following Y". Therefore, I need a WebSocket server (maybe node.js or socket.io). If I do so I will have two servers running on the same EC2 instance (the web server and the socket server), but how can I pass the events/notifications from the web server to the socket server?

I guess there should be something in the middle, right? Something that AWS can offer me. Or is there a way to feed the socket server directly?

What would be a good approach for this situation?

A derivated question is: where is the best place to get the friend list that will recieve the notification? Should it be the web server or socket server?

Answer (score 0):

You need a proxy in front of your 2 servers which will delegate requests to either your Pyramid app or to node.js depending on the URL or some other request parameters.

The other option is to run Pyramid in gevent and utilize [gevent_socketio](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent-socketio/0.3.5-beta) to do your work all within the same application.

Comment: 1. It seems that that [pyramid_socketio](https://github.com/abourget/pyramid_socketio) is deprecated. Instead they support [gevent-socketio](https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio) . However, if I use the same server wouldn't that overkill the pyramid application?

Comment: 2. Still, how can I feed the node.js server from the pyramid application.

Comment: forgot that they moved most of the pyramid_socketio code into gevent_socketio.. what do you mean "overkill the pyramid application"?? And what do you mean by "feed" the node.js server? Typically the different applications are independent with a shared data model.

Comment: Well, when I think about the socket server having 100000 users connected and then trying to send a message for only 100 of them, I imagine a time costly thing. So, If I use gevent-socketio I suppose that the thread will not continue until those messages are sent. That said, the server would be paying a lot of attention to the socket part rather than to the web part. Thats why I suppose both should not be together and that the web server sends the notifications to the socket server (the web server feeds the socket server with notifications). Am I right in any of this assumptions?

Comment: a) gevent is not threaded b) in the unlikely event that you actually have 100000 concurrent connections then you'll need a more complex system to scale out whether you're on node.js or python.